# Select different strings in the same row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called "character_certifications" where I need to select different strings as count in the same result. The table looks like this:

---

### classId      charId                var

```
0       268482320       EmergentAbility65-1
0       268482320       EmergentAbility65-2
0       268482320       EmergentAbility65-3

0       268482320       EmergentAbility70-1
0       268482320       EmergentAbility70-2
0       268482320       EmergentAbility70-3

0       268482320       ClassAbility75-1
0       268482320       ClassAbility75-2
0       268482320       ClassAbility75-3

0       268482320       ClassAbility80-1
0       268482320       ClassAbility80-2
0       268482320       ClassAbility80-3
```

and I need an output like this:

```
for emergentAbilities 65 and 70 = result count 6
```

I tried with this SQL request but it returns me 1 :

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct var) AS COUNT 
from character_certifications 
where classId=0 AND charId=268482320 AND var"EmergentAbility65-1"
```

and I also tried with this and it returned me 12:

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct var) AS COUNT 
from character_certifications 
where classId=0 AND charId=268482320
```

How to do the sum of all emergent Abilities 65 and 70?

and in some cases the characters havent "all" emergent abilities 65 and 70 they can have for example:

Comment: Do you need exactly the abilities `65` and `70` or could it be "all the EmergentAbility for some user"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try with something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct var) AS COUNT 
from character_certifications 
where classId=0 AND charId=268482320 
AND (var LIKE "EmergentAbility65%" OR var LIKE "EmergentAbility70%")
```

Try it [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dfef2b/1/0).

Answer (score 0):

If you can, adjust your schema to either split that compound string, or to have the two key components broken out into derivative columns so that you can quickly sum them. Then it's as easy as:

```
SELECT var, SUM(column_b)
  FROM character_certifications
  WHERE column_a IN ('EmergentAbility65', 'EmergentAbility70')
  GROUP BY column_a
```

Where `column_a` and `column_b` represent the two components of `var`. If those columns are indexed this query runs very quickly.

If you can't do that you will have to endure a very expensive table scan using things like `SUBSTRING_INDEX(var, '-', -1)` to extract the components. This tends to be extremely slow on large tables.